# Connecting linksys AE2500 with raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi, which i want to connect to a wifi adapter. 
I can't seem to tet it to work. 
How should it be done?

Maybe my wifi adapter is not supported?
How can i check it?

Comment: Anyone cab help me in this matter?

Answer (score 0):

if you have followed [these](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) steps from raspberrypi.org

you can check by typing in:

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

Sometimes the drivers aren't built into the kernel.  From what i've found this one isn't.  [forum link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18849&p=246833)